# Generating evenly distributed multiples/samples within a range

Tags: python

**Specific instance of Problem**
I have an int range from 1-100. I want to generate n total numbers within this range that are **as evenly distributed as possible** and include the first and last values.

**Example**

```
start = 1, end = 100, n = 5   
Output: [1, 25, 50, 75, 100]

start = 1, end = 100, n = 4   
Output: [1, 33, 66, 100]

start = 1, end = 100, n = 2   
Output: [1, 100]
```

**What I currently have**
I actually have a working approach but I keep feeling I am over thinking this and missing something more simple? Is this the most efficient approach or could this be improved?

```python
def steps(start, end, n):
    n = min(end, max(n, 2) - 1)
    mult = end / float(n)
    yield start
    for scale in xrange(1, n+1):
        val = int(mult * scale)
        if val != start:
            yield val
```

Note, I am ensuring that this function will always return at least the lower and upper limit values of the range. So, I force `n >= 2`

Just for search reference, I am using this to sample image frames from a rendered sequence, where you would usually want the first, middle, last. But I wanted to be able to scale a bit better to handle really long image sequences and get better coverage.

**Solved: From the selected answer**

I ended up using this slightly modified version of @vartec's answer, to be a generator, and also cap the `n` value for safety:

```
def steps(start,end,n):
    n = min(end, max(n, 2))
    step = (end-start)/float(n-1)
    return (int(round(start+x*step)) for x in xrange(n))
```

Comment: Your code doesn't handle `list(steps(50,100,3))`

Comment: `[1, 33, 66, 100]` is not most even possible, it should be `[1, 33, 67, 100]`, after all 66.66(6) should be rounded up, not down.

Comment: For example 2 your numbers are not evenly spaced (see my answer) or do I miss something?

Comment: @bmu: You didn't miss anything. I forgot to use `round` to make it even closer.

Comment: @vartec: You are right, I forgot to use `round` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need proper rounding:

```
def steps(start,end,n):
    if n<2:
        raise Exception("behaviour not defined for n<2")
    step = (end-start)/float(n-1)
    return [int(round(start+x*step)) for x in range(n)]
```

Comment: Thanks for simplifying this. I overlooked the `round` most likely because this specific application isn't as sensitive to say, 66 vs 67, so it didn't raise a flag to me.

Comment: @NathanRossPowell: there

Answer (score 4):

Extra dependency and maybe overkill, but short, tested and should give correct results: [numpy.linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace)

```
>>> numpy.linspace(1, 100, 4).astype(int).tolist()
[1, 34, 67, 100]
```

Comment: Ah really cool! I wanted to limit my dependencies in this case but I voted this up and will remember that this is available. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using `range` is that the step must be an integer and so you get rounding issues, such as `steps(1,100,4) == [1, 33, 66, 100]`. If you want integer outputs but want as even a step as possible, use a float as your step.

```
>>> def steps(start,end,n):
...    step = (end-start)/float(n-1)
...    return [int(round(start+i*step)) for i in range(n)]

>>> steps(1,100,5)
>>> [1, 26, 51, 75, 100]
>>> steps(1,100,4)
>>> [1, 34, 67, 100]
>>> steps(1,100,2)
>>> [1, 100]
>>>
```

Comment: @vartec: Did he fix that rounding issue before you commented? It said you commented on it after he must have fixed it, and now you both have identical answers. I was trying to figure out who had that first since I wanted to accept it.

Comment: @jdi: It's quite easy to check, just hover over *'N hours ago'*. His edit is 10 minutes after my answer.

Comment: @vartec: Ah I was comparing them wrong. Was looking at the timestamp of his edit vs your comment (Not your answer vs his edit).

Comment: @vartec: I missed your answer when I came back to edit. To what 33.33 are you referring?

Comment: @IainRist: NVM, my bad, I was counting from 0. Anyway, doesn't matter, you got my upvote, as your answer is also correct one.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> def steps(start,end,n):
        yield start
        begin = start if start>1 else 0
        c = count(begin,(end-begin)/(n-1))
        next(c)
        for _ in range(n-2):
            yield next(c)
        yield end


>>> list(steps(1,100,2))
[1, 100]
>>> list(steps(1,100,5))
[1, 25, 50, 75, 100]
>>> list(steps(1,100,4))
[1, 33, 66, 100]
>>> list(steps(50,100,3))
[50, 75, 100]
>>> list(steps(10,100,10))
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Can be shortened to

```
>>> from itertools import islice, count
>>> def steps(start,end,n):
        yield start
        begin = start if start>1 else 0
        c = islice(count(begin,(end-begin)/(n-1)),1,None)
        for _ in range(n-2):
            yield next(c)
        yield end
```

Comment: Both you and @Abhijit have great suggestions so far, but they both have an issue with `n == 4`. They return 5 results that aren't distributed evenly.

Comment: Thanks for the updated version! I voted it up, but some people came up with a shorter version that also fixed my little rounding oversight as well.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using [range](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html)? Here is how you can use it

```
>>> def steps(start,end,n):
    return [start]+range(start-1,end,end/(n-1))[1:]+[end]

>>> steps(1,100,5)
[1, 25, 50, 75, 100]
>>> steps(1,100,2)
[1, 100]
>>>
```

Comment: Wow i had exactly the same code as you... the race condition... :D

Comment: :-) Well You could have posted it. At least people would understand based on time difference

Comment: Nah, better not... it causes confusion. +1 btw

Comment: I really like where this is going but it has an issue when `n == 4` compared to how mine handles it. Same issue with the answer from @jamylak

Comment: Sorry, it just not numerically stable. You have problems with rounding errors: `steps(1,100,15)` -> `[1, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 77, 84, 91, 98, 100]`