# Looking for a array reducing algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an array of a structures containing two float values `x` and `y`.

- `x` is the position on a x-axis in mm (0.0mm to e.g. 2500.0mm)
- `y` is a height measurement in mm at the x-position (0.0mm to e.g. 50.0mm)

With the length of 2500.0mm I will have an array filled up with 2501 values (one for each mm). As i want to send this array to a visualization which will draw that on a x/y plot i want to reduce that array to exactly 500 values (more than 500 values will slow down the communication too much). Now you might say.. well okay, than just take every 5th value. But what to do if my array has 1653 values? I would have to take every 3,306th value. I definitely need the first and the last value.

Is there any elegant algorithm that might help me out?

Comment: Can you resample the data? For example, can the value at x = 5.5 be considered `(y[5] + y[6]) / 2`?

Comment: Yes that would not be a problem!

Comment: If you don't want to interpolate, you can also increase step by `ceil(i * step)` or `round(i * step)`  where `step` is a floating point value. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084436/generating-evenly-distributed-multiples-samples-within-a-range) or  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873626/choose-m-evenly-spaced-elements-from-a-sequence-of-length-n) for code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **[interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation)** to estimate a function that is similar to yours, and then you could just choose the desired points in the data range and estimate their value. Then, you could simply plot these values.

This is elegant and pretty easy to generalize for more or less points, as long as you stay within the range of original data (and do not try to extrapolate out of this range)